# react handler array from axios

Tags: arrays, reactjs, axios

How I handle the value array from Axios and fill the card
get the value from the array and show data

```
import React, { Component, Suspense } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import {Card} from "reactstrap";

import { PHP } from "../../constants";

//api url adress server
const api = PHP;
const reqtoken = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token");

class Property extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  load() {
    axios
      .get(api + "api/property", {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          Authorization: reqtoken
        }
      })
```

insert the data array on the state

```
      .then(json => {
```

console.log show the data on console terminal

```
        console.log(json.data.data.data);
        this.setState({
          data: json.data.data.data
        });
      })
      .catch(erros => {
        console.log(erros);
      });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.load();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
```

map the array to handle the result................

```
        {this.state.data.map(i => (
          <Card>
            <li>{i.address}</li>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Property;
```

didn't make me a wrong error console

Comment: can you update you're question with sample response that you're getting from api.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the response data comes in, but I found a problem with the code. You should pass keys.

```js
{this.state.data.map(item => (
  <Card key={item.id}>
    <li>{item.address}</li>
  </Card>
))}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys